# Packet Tracer Libraries Needed (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, shared-libraries, dynamic-library, ld-preload

I was able, easily, to download and install this on Ubuntu with the .deb file. I am currently using Crunchbang and I simply cannot get it to install.

Running it, I get error after error asking for library after library.

After installing all of these and more, I was able to clear up the libQt4* libraries.

```
apt-get install -y lib32-libpng lib32-libsm lib32-libxi lib32-libxrandr lib32-freetype2 lib32-fontconfig lib32-glib2 lib32-libstdc++5 extra/qtwebkit multilib/lib32-qt
```

My current error:

```
root@crunchbang:/usr/local/PacketTracer6/bin# ./PacketTracer6 
./PacketTracer6: error while loading shared libraries: libQt3Support.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I cannot find a package that contains this nor can I find it online. I have already downloaded libraries and `LD_PRELOAD` libraries to it.

ldd output:

```
./PacketTracer6: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./PacketTracer6)
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76e5000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xf7509000)
    libQtWebKit.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4 (0xf5dbe000)
    libQtScriptTools.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtScriptTools.so.4 (0xf5d06000)
    libQtScript.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4 (0xf5a7a000)
    libQt3Support.so.4 => not found
    libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4 (0xf5a38000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0xf4f54000)
    libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0xf4e10000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0xf4b2a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xf4b11000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf4a25000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xf49ff000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf49e1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xf487d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xf4879000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf4860000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0xf47b0000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf47a5000)
    libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0xf4797000)
    libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0xf4785000)
    libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0xf4761000)
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0xf4743000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0xf46df000)
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0xf45f5000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf45a3000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf44a6000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf436e000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf4337000)
    libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0xf431d000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf42f3000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf4257000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xf424f000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xf4235000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf4223000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xf421a000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76e6000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0xf4189000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf4183000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0xf402f000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xf402c000)
    libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5 (0xf4023000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf3fe5000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf3fc1000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf3f99000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0xf3f3c000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf3f39000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf3f33000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xf3f0b000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf3f05000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Running 'file' on PacketTracer6 ($ file PacketTracer6 )
shows the executable to be 32-bit.

It won't run at all on amd64 OS's without the supporting 
32-bit libraries installed.

That is you need to set up your system as a multi-architecture
one.

On debian it's # dpkg --add-architecture i386

I haven't completed this, yet, so I don't know how many of 
the necessary libs go in by default,
 and how many would have
to be installed slowly and by hand.

If someone else beats me to it, feel free to add to this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile/install libQt3 because PacketTracer6 requires libQt3 library as ldd shows

```
libQt3Support.so.4 => not found
```

you need to install `libqt4-qt3support` from synaptic package manager

Answer (score 1):

The packed in libraries depend on GCLIB 2.15 but wheezy comes with 2.13. 
This helped for me:

```
apt-get install libqt4-qt3support:i386
apt-get install libqt4-scripttools:i386
mv /opt/pt/lib /opt/pt/lib.bak
mkdir /opt/pt/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt* /opt/pt/lib
```